# Python Singleton for algebraic data types with match support

Tags: python, algebraic-data-types

A common pattern I use in languages with algebraic data types is hierarchical data class hierarchies. For example, in Kotlin I might have:

```
sealed class Thing {
    data class CoolThing(val coolness: Int) : Thing()
    data class OtherThing(val other: String) : Thing()
    object BoringThing : Thing()
}
```

I can somewhat emulate this in Python as follows:

```
from dataclasses import dataclass
from typing import Literal

@dataclass
class CoolThing:
    coolness: int

@dataclass
class OtherThing:
    other: str

BoringThing = object()

Thing = CoolThing | OtherThing | Literal[BoringThing]
```

However, this leaves some issues.

First of all, the requirement that each "singleton" object value needs to be wrapped in `Literal` quickly becomes tedious if there are a lot of them. I already use a custom singleton class instead of just `object` to construct them in real code (to override e.g. `__str__`), I suspect that there should be some way to make the object both a metaclass and a class in and of itself. I just can't figure it out.

Secondly, the match statement doesn't seem to work on the "singleton" objects as expected since it seems to be binding to the name, not the value. Again, I suspect I am missing either some syntax or some data model behaviour that will allow what I want.

Here is a sample of what I would like to be possible:

```
from dataclasses import dataclass

# <Some kind of declaration of SingletonObject>

@dataclass
class CoolThing:
    coolness: int

@dataclass
class OtherThing:
    other: str

BoringThing = SingletonObject()

Thing = CoolThing | OtherThing | BoringThing

# Later, supported matching like so (assuming thing is a Thing):
match thing:
    case BoringThing:
        print('This is boring')
    case OtherThing(other):
        print(f'This is {other}')
    case CoolThing(coolness):
        print(f'This is {coolness} cool')
```

Is there any way to achieve that behaviour? Is there any other solution (maybe some kind of elaborated enum value system or custom annotation)?